# Python looping list

Tags: python

I have function 1

```
def predict(x, y):
    z = []
    for i in x:
        if i >= y:
            z.append(1)
        else:
            z.append(0)
    return z
```

Now, for each thresholds value, I want to use that and pred_probs to call my first function and then populate the empty lists.
so the first call would be predict(pred_probs, .0.00). the second call in the loop would be predict(pred_probs, 0.25) and so on.  each loop would append the output the lists

```
   pred_1 = []
    pred_2 = []
    pred_3 = []
    pred_4 = []
    pred_5 = []
    thresholds = [0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00]
    pred_probs = [0.875, 0.325, 0.6, 0.09, 0.4]

    for i in thresholds:
        pred =  predict(pred_probs,i)
        pred1.append(pred)
```

The desired outcome would be

```
pred_1 = [1,1,1,1,1]
pred_2 = [1,1,1,0,1]
pred_3 = [1,0,1,0,0]
pred_4 = [1,0,0,0,0]
pred_5 = [0,0,0,0,0]
```

the problem is that I'm not sure how to access the lists individually.

this is the output i receive:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

however, i'm not sure how to take the first list and assign it to pred_1 and then son

Comment: You haven't indicated a problem or asked a question.

Comment: Don't create 5 lists.  Create a two-dimensional structure, with one list containing 5 lists.  Now it's an easy nested loop problem.  Careful how you initialize the list.  `preds = [[] for _ in range(5)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do exactly what you asked.

```py
for i, arr in zip(thresholds, [pred_1, pred_2, pred_3, pred_4, pred_5]):
    pred = predict(pred_probs, i)
    arr.extend(pred)
```

However, you may consider whether 5 lists is really what you want. It might be easier to do

```py
pred = []
for i in thresholds:
    vals = predict(pred_probs, i)
    pred.append(vals)
print(pred)
```

This will give

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I believe 5 lists is what I need because I then need to take those lists and dump them into another function...your way is most likely cleaner but i'm not sure i fully understand it so I may go with the more basic approach...or at least the approach i understand.

Answer (score 1):

here's an alternate way that vectorizes the function

```
import numpy as np


def predict(x, y):
    if x >= y:
        return 1
    return 0


thresholds = [0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00]
pred_probs = [0.875, 0.325, 0.6, 0.09, 0.4]

pred_lists = np.ndarray(shape=(len(thresholds), len(pred_probs)), dtype=np.int32)

v_predict = np.vectorize(predict)

for n, threshold in enumerate(thresholds):
    pred_lists[n, :] = v_predict(pred_probs, threshold)
print(pred_lists)
```

Output

```
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: i'm actually getting this error out of no where...it was working fine and now i see:  TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Comment: i just tried opening up a fresh file and i'm seeing that error still

Comment: I'm not sure where that error would be coming from if you are running the same code.  I'm using Python v 3.9 and numpy v 1.21.1.  You say the error is just coming out of nowhere - did you change something in between the time it worked and when it did not work?